# LINQ: Populating a LIST<> via multiple navigations

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Ok, I'll try and make this make sense.

In  a model, Lead, among other properties, we have these:

```
public class Lead
{
    ....
    public int LeadID {get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuoteRevision> QuoteRevisions { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And QuoteRevision...

```
public class QuoteRevision
{
    ....
    [ForeignKey(nameof(LeadID))]
    public virtual Lead Lead { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuoteRevisionProduct> QuoteRevisionProduct{ get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And the model for QuoteRevisionProduct:

```
public class QuoteRevisionProduct
{
    ....
    [ForeignKey(nameof(QuoteRevisionID))]
    public virtual QuoteRevision QuoteRevision { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And last of all...

```
public class Product
{
    ....
    public string Code { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Ok.  So these are the models I need to query to build an object called QuoteSearchItem that has multiple properties. Here's two of them:

```
public class QuoteSearchItem
{
    ....
    public LeadID {get; set; }
    public List<string> Codes { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I'm starting with this IQueryable of all rows in Lead:

```
leads = IQueryable<Lead>
```

And then doing this:

```
var results = from l in leads
    from qr in l.QuoteRevisions
    from rp in qr.RevisionProducts
    select new QuoteSearchItem
    {
        ....
        LeadID = l.LeadID,
        AdditionalProducts = ???
        ....
    };
```

I'm not sure how to get that list of Codes.  I can do this:

```
 Code = rp.Product.Code,
```

And that will get me a single code, the first in the list.  But how do I get ALL that match?

I know this was a lot to follow. I hope it makes sense.  Thank you!

**EDIT:**

This is (almost) the SQL that I'm looking for:

```
SELECT 
    l.ID,
    p.Code
FROM 
    dbo.Leads AS l
    JOIN QuoteRevisions qr ON qr.LeadID = l.ID
    JOIN QuoteRevisionProducts qrp on qrp.QuoteRevisionID = qr.QuoteRevisionID
    JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = qrp.ProductID
```

Except that this will just return multiple rows per product.  But, at least it gives an idea.

**EDIT 2:**

```
Code = l.QuoteRevisions.SelectMany(qr => qr.RevisionProducts).Select(p => p.Product.Code).ToList()
```

This doesn't throw an error, but it's returning a row of data for each code, which isn't what I need.

Comment: Can't you do `Codes = l.QuoteRevisions.SelectMany(qr => qr.SelectMany(qri => qri.QuoteRevisionProduct).Select(p => p.Code)`

Comment: Can you put that as an answer?  qr. Won't have SelectMany as an option, but I see where you are headed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the models and get all the codes, something like this:

```
var results = from l in leads    
select new QuoteSearchItem
{
    ....
    LeadID = l.LeadID,
    Codes = l.QuoteRevisions.SelectMany(qr => qr.QuoteRevisionProduct)
            .Select(p => p.Product.Code)
    ....
};
```

not sure how your DB looks, but you can probably use `Distinct` as well to eliminate duplicate `Codes`

Comment: Ok, we are headed in the right direction,  but I get a compile error on qr.SelectMany(..). QuoteRevisions does not not contain a definition for 'SelectMany'

Comment: Yes, just updated it, I *think* that should work, but can't test it at the moment

Comment: oh man we are getting close!  This isn't just it, but I'll keep playing.

Comment: what's incorrect about it? is it returning duplicates or is something else wrong?

Comment: QuoteRevision does not contain a definition for QuoteRevisionProduct.  I'm going to modify my OP with what I've got based on your suggestions. I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)